# The meaning of a dot in ".venv" folder after it's created via VSCode IDE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv, virtual-environment

Good day, everyone.

I'm wondering why is there a dot or in other words "." in ".venv" folder when I create a virtual environemnt for Python coding? It seems it's working with no problem if I try a little bit different ways to create v. environment and name it however I want... Is there something I'm missing perhaps?

Thanks for your attention.

[Example of ".venv" folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR1S3.png)

I have tried via VSCode with built-in function as described below:

1. Ctrl + Shift + P
2. Find the "Python: Create Environment" command within the drop-down list
3. Then I've chosen "venv" option
4. Chose the version of Python I have on my PC

After all, it automatically created a ".venv" aka virutal environment

Comment: The reason for the dot is so it's an invisible/hidden folder. This is among other things indicate that it is a special directory for holding a virtual environment + the fact it's not viewable when you open your project folder from file explorer for instance.